# Создание удалённой сети в Win

Tags: windows, сеть

Как можно создать сеть между 2 удалёнными пк через интернет? Есть какой-то аналог  `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ID key=KEY` , но подключение через интернет, а не wi-fi?

Comment: А зачем? Просто от ответа на этот вопрос зависит и ответ.

Comment: Например для передачи данных, работы с общими папками

Comment: https://syncthing.net/, https://www.resilio.com/. Оно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://itadept.ru/windows-vpn-server/ - это как создать vpn сервер.
https://ivstar.net/nastroyka-vpn-podklyucheniya-v-windows-xp-vista-i-7.html - это как к нему подключиться.
Если я правильно Вас понял, и Вам это нужно.